# Change format of IIS HTTP Error logging

Tags: iis, logging

HTTP.sys by default creates [error log](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/820729/error-logging-in-http-apis) files under C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR.

Is it possible to change the format of these log files to include other fields including cs-host and cs-uri-query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This list from Microsoft is a bit of outdated, as it does not include the recently introduced "**streamid**" field present in Windows Server 2016, but it definitely can help you specify the fields you need.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/http/error-logging-in-windows-server-2003-sp1

To quickly sum all the Hex values, just type them in Google as is (in this example I choosed to include all fields, including the new `streamid` fields available since Windows Server 2016 and above) :

`0x00000001 + 0x00000002 + 0x00000004 + 0x00000020 + 0x00000040 + 0x00000080 + 0x00000400 + 0x00001000 + 0x00002000 + 0x00004000 + 0x00008000 + 0x00010000 + 0x00020000 + 0x00040000 + 0x00080000 + 0x00100000 + 0x00400000 + 0x00800000 + 0x01000000 + 0x02000000 + 0x04000000 + 0x08000000`

That will return `0xFDFF4E7` !

Just create then execute a new .REG file with this content :

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters]

; WIN 2016-2019-2022
; LOG THE FOLLOWING #Fields: date time s-computername c-ip c-port s-ip s-port cs-version cs-method cs-uri cs(User-Agent) cs(Cookie) cs(Referer) cs-host sc-status sc-bytes cs-bytes time-taken s-siteid s-reason s-queuename streamid
"ErrorLoggingFields"=dword:0fdff4e7
```

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on the earlier answer you need to assign a value to the following registry entry for chosen fields.

`[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters] "ErrorLoggingFields"=dword:0fc884c7`

Basically the value is a sum of all the bit values from the list below for whichever fields you want included.

| Log field | Logged by default | Bit value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Date | Yes | 0x00000001 |
| Time | Yes | 0x00000002 |
| Client IP Address | Yes | 0x00000004 |
| Server Computer Name | No | 0x00000020 |
| Server IP Address | Yes | 0x00000040 |
| Method | Yes | 0x00000080 |
| Protocol Status | Yes | 0x00000400 |
| SC-Bytes | No | 0x00001000 |
| CS-Bytes | No | 0x00002000 |
| Time Taken | No | 0x00004000 |
| Server Port | Yes | 0x00008000 |
| User Agent | No | 0x00010000 |
| Cookie | No | 0x00020000 |
| referrer | No | 0x00040000 |
| Protocol Version | Yes | 0x00080000 |
| Host | No | 0x00100000 |
| Client Port | Yes | 0x00400000 |
| URI | Yes | 0x00800000 |
| SiteId | Yes | 0x01000000 |
| Reason Phrase | Yes | 0x02000000 |
| Queue Name | Yes | 0x04000000 |
| Stream Id | Yes | 0x08000000 |

Comment: See [HTTP_LOG_FIELD_ Constants](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/http/http-log-field--constants) from http.h for field descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround:

1. Create a header file using the columns of your HTTPErr log file in the same order and save it as - header.txt
2. Use the following format for your SQL query

   LogParser.exe "select sc-status, s-reason, s-queuename, count(* ) from C:\temp\HTTPLogs*.log group by sc-status, s-reason, s-queuename order by count(*) desc" -i:TSV -iseparator:space -iHeaderFile C:\temp\HTTPLogs\header.txt